# I get a 404 error whenever i try to get login page or signup page, after I did my second commit

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, bcrypt

At first, the problem was that I got a 404 error whenever I tried to submit/post the signup or login form, so a friend of mine told me to change a couple of things, but then after my second commit I now get 404 error whenever I try to get the Login or Sign Up Page

This is my whole project, on my Github.

https://github.com/tigerabrodi/blogcms

I'd highly appreciate if someone could take his time to have a look into this and help me to solve this problem.

I wanna be able to not just get the login or sign up page, but also to be able to post them and then save the user into the database.

Comment: `404` Status code that indicated your routes is not found. So Could you please check you are calling correct routes.

Comment: PS. Is there any runtime error you are getting? (besides logical 404 error)

Comment: @tiger-abrodi if my answer fixed your issue and it makes sense to you, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you simply forgot to include `authRoutes` (defined [here](https://github.com/tigerabrodi/blogcms/blob/64d74a662ace3b3e12813f8a1f9e45f2ddf2defc/app.js#L31)) using `app.use(...)`. This is why it gives you 404 - the routes such as `GET /signup` or `GET /login` are not defined.

So, the solution would be to add `app.use(authRoutes)` on [this line](https://github.com/tigerabrodi/blogcms/blob/master/app.js#L80) below other routes you have defined previously.

Let me know if this works.